# Find $\lim_{x\uparrow 1}\mathbb{P}(F_Y(Y)>x|F_X(X)>x)$ where $X,Y$ poisson

Tags: probability-theory, distribution-tails, copula

Let $X=Y_1+N,Y=Y_2+N$ where $N\sim \text{pois}(\lambda), Y_1\sim \text{pois}(\lambda_1), Y_2\sim \text{pois}(\lambda_2)$ and $N,Y_1,Y_2$ are independent. I'm asked to find $$\lim_{x\uparrow 1}\mathbb{P}(F_Y(Y)>x|F_X(X)>x).$$I have been trying to rewrite this (using that $F_Y(Y)\sim \text{Uniform}(0,1)$) but can't get it to work out. We also have a result that states that $$\lim_{x\uparrow 1}\mathbb{P}(F_Y(Y)>x|F_X(X)>x)=\lim_{x\uparrow 1}\frac{1-2x+C(x,x)}{1-x}$$where $C$ is the copula for $(X,Y)$ i.e. $$F_{(X,Y)}(x,y)=C(F_X(x),F_Y(y)).$$We know from [distribution of bivariate poisson](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/108705/deriving-the-bivariate-poisson-distribution) that $$F_{(X,Y)}(x,y)=e^{-(\lambda+\lambda_1+\lambda_2)}\sum_{i=0}^{\min(x,y)}\frac{\lambda^i}{i!}\frac{\lambda_1^{x-i}}{(x-i)!}\frac{\lambda_2^{y-i}}{(y-i)!}$$and that $X\sim \text{pois}(\lambda+\lambda_1), Y\sim \text{pois}(\lambda+\lambda_2)$ however I have not been able to find $C$. Help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think your definition of $C$ is not correct. $C(x,y)$ should be defined as $$C(x,y) = P(F_X(X) \le x, F_Y(Y) \le y) = F_{F_X(X), F_Y(Y)}(x,y).$$

Comment: @angryavian https://imgur.com/a/fZdjIFi, this is the definition of copula in the book we use. Maybe I'm not reading it correctly.

Comment: My mistake, I think both formulations are equivalent via $P(F_X(X) \le F_X(x), F_Y(Y) \le F_Y(y)) = P(X \le x, Y \le y)$. Please disregard my previous comment.